# How to prepare a date and double for a mysql replace statement?

Tags: mysql, date-format, floating-point, replace

I have a MySql table with three columns:

```
CU VARCHAR(3)
DA DATETIME
VA DOUBLE
```

I need to execute several `REPLACE into mytable (CU, DA, VA) values("ABC", mydate, myval)` statements from Java. `mydate` is a `Date` and `myval` is a `double`.

My question is, assuming I have a connection to my database, how do I format and include `mydate` and `myval` properly in this string statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the output of the [NOW() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

```
mysql> select now();
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 2012-04-24 22:07:47 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

This is the format to enter `mydate`. For a double, just append `.0` to any integer. No need for numbers to to have quotes:

```
REPLACE into mytable (CU, DA, VA) values('ABC', '2012-04-24 22:07:47', 23.0);
```